# psycopg2.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint DETAIL: Key (id)=(19) already exists

Tags: python, django

I am not setting the primary key manually. How could this be happening?

```
class Image(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='attack_images', blank=True, null=True)
    source_url = models.URLField(blank=True,null=True)
    domain = models.ForeignKey(Domain, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True,null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True,null=True)
```

In my 5 years of programming in Django I've never gotten this error. I can't tell what is going wrong by just looking at my code and the traceback. What could be wrong? Let me know if I need to post more code. Thanks in advance. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try to fix it by python manage.py migrate

Comment: No migrations to apply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to save your submodel in your save method.

```
self.image.save(
                os.path.basename(self.source_url),
                File(open(result[0], 'rb'))
                )
```

Therefore you are saving your model before calling super's save method. You should set your image but not save it before calling super's save method.

```
self.image = os.path.basename(self.source_url),File(open(result[0], 'rb'))
```

Comment: where are you getting `result` from?

Comment: you can check the question, i did not copy the whole question, only the line to be changed...

Comment: tried `attack_image_object.image = img_filename, File(img_temp)`. same error

Comment: oh, yes there is, in models. thanks. i was looking in the first section. trying your solution. if it works, +10

Comment: this helped, though now I'm getting "AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute '_committed'"

Comment: can you give more detail about the error you get now? It sounds like it is a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess a possible solution it's:

```
./manage.py migrate appname zero
```

modify appname with name of your application.
then :

```
python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
```